# Can I stack items like Gravitrino balls?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I've found some Gravitrino balls, and they're taking up a lot of inventory slots, can I stack these items at all?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, but you initially loose 5 balls to start off with. If you craft an upgrade that requires 10 Gravitrino balls, and the destruct it, you get what looks like 1 Gravitrino ball back, but it's actually a 100 stack, containing 5 balls, now you can just stack the rest up with it.

This maybe considered a bug and might change in the future. I don't know if this works with any other high value item as I've only come across Gravitrino balls so far.

Comment: Stacking is not possible with other items right? (such as Fascination beads for example)

Comment: I don't now a blueprint that requires Fascination Beads so I can't try it unfortunately.

Comment: @Mr.Meeseeks Things like Fascination Beads, which as far as we know aren't used for crafting in any way, cannot be stacked.

Comment: Ok, so basicly only crafting items can be stacked. Too bad though because some of those other items sell for quite the buck!

Comment: That is almost definitely a bug. But is interesting. I really wish we could stack things to at least 5 or 10 naturally... so much inventory space dedicated to GrahGrah's and Gravitino Balls.

Comment: @Mr.Meeseeks Yeah I imagine the selling price is exactly why they can't be stacked. A full 100 stack of Gravitrino balls sells for ~2.75 mill

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can stack the Tradable (white) items. Most have a pretty low stack count though. But different storage areas allow for different amounts to be in a single stack.

- 5 for your main Backpack
- Stacks of 10 in your Cargo
- Stacks of 20 in Storage Containers